# Excel - Pivot table drill down using SUMIF

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, pivot-table

Not sure if this is possible, maybe with VBA but I can't work it out.

I have a pivot table that I want to be able to filter totals to separate totals less than/greater than a value. (eg all totals >5)

I have a SUMIF calculation that is doing this which sits on the worksheet outside the pivot table. I would like to be able to drill down into the excluded totals and their related data like you would by double clicking data inside the pivot table.

Is this possible, perhaps with VBA? If so some direction for a place to start would be good.
I want to be able to extract the data that is represented in the pivot tables highlighted values.
[Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiTqE.png)

[Drill Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfO87.png)

I need all the values included within the pivot table for other calculations, however, I need to be able to separate drill down data based on totals

Comment: Add some screen shots or examples of your data before and after.

Comment: what examples are you looking for? the Pivot table itself, the data the pivot table uses, what a drill down looks like? Sorry Im a bit confused, just want to know if it is possible to have a cell outside the pivot table but on the same worksheet produce a drill down like the pivot table does when double clicked. However, the cell I am using uses a =SUMIF function to filter out results. Can I drill down into these filtered results? What screen shot would help with this?

Comment: A screenshot that shows some sample data and the mocked up expected result.

Comment: added 2 in the description